# mongoexport query multiple field error (too many positional options have been specified on the command line)

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I am trying to mongoexport (Version 2.6) MongoDB data into csv format using the command as follows

```
$ mongoexport  --port 27017 -d test -q {userId:123 , name:'John'} -c  user_datas -f userId --csv -o /myOutFile.csv
```

and I get

```
"Error parsing command line: too many positional options have been specified on the command line"
```

But if I query those two conditions separately it works fine :

```
$ mongoexport  --port 27017 -d test -q {userId:123} -c user_datas -f userId --csv -o /myOutFile.csv
```

and

```
$ mongoexport  --port 27017 -d test -q {name:'John'} -c user_datas -f userId --csv -o /myOutFile.csv
```

What is the problem of the first `mongoexport` command ?

Comment: Your shell has no idea of the semantics of MongoDB. So you should quote the query string: `mongoexport  --port 27017 -d test -q "{userId:123 , name:'John'}"…`

Comment: Thank u @MarkusWMahlberg !
it works